# How to show single series when multi line chart renders

Tags: charts, extjs5

I have a line chart with multiple lines(created using different Y-fields) using ExtJS5. When chart renders all the lines are showed by default.

But my client wants to see only first line(first series line) when chart  renders for first time. Later when he selects the other items from legend corresponding lines has to be showed.

Is there any option to do this?
Thanks in advance...

Regards,
Vin

Answer (score 0):

I got the answer as below:

var chart = Ext.getCmp('processchartid');
for(var i = 1; i< chart.series.length; i++){

```
 chart.series[i].setHidden(true);
```

}

chart.redraw();

Use setHidden on series is hiding that specific series.